How can I use <forceChatter:publisher> and <forceChatter:feed> in a Lightning Web Component (LWC)?
I understand these are standard Aura components in Salesforce, and they cannot be directly used in LWC. Is there a recommended approach to integrate their functionality into an LWC, or any workaround for this limitation?
I’ve already tried the following:
Using <lightning:container>, but I encountered a "module not found" error during deployment.
Implementing an Aura application to host the components and integrate them into LWC, but it still failed to load.

Could you please guide me on how to achieve this or suggest another solution?

We cannot use aura components inside lightning web components.

Aura components can contain Lightning web components. However, the opposite doesn’t apply. Lightning web components can’t contain Aura components.

Reference Link
For your use case you might need to use lwc and apex like below:
Chatter Post Publisher Component:
HTML
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Post to Chatter">
        <lightning-input label="Post Body" value={postBody} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-button label="Post" onclick={handlePost}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

JS
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import createFeedPost from '@salesforce/apex/ChatterFeedController.createFeedPost';

export default class ChatterPostPublisher extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;  // The record ID to post to
    postBody = '';   

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.postBody = event.target.value;
    }

    handlePost() {
        if (this.postBody) {
            createFeedPost({ recordId: this.recordId, body: this.postBody })
                .then(() => {
                    this.postBody = ''; 
                    console.log('Post created');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error creating post', error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log('Please enter text to post.');
        }
    }
}

Controller:
public with sharing class ChatterFeedController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<FeedItem> getFeedItems(String recordId) {
        return [
            SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Body, CreatedById, ParentId
            FROM FeedItem
            WHERE ParentId = :recordId
            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
        ];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createFeedPost(String recordId, String body) {
        FeedItem feedPost = new FeedItem(
            ParentId = recordId,  
            Body = body           
        );
        insert feedPost;
    }
}

If you want to get post you can use: ChatterFeedController.getFeedItems;
Kindly acknowledge whether this is the solution you were looking for.

Thanks  raditz2077 I want to know is there standard component for chatters in Lightning Web Component for Publisher , Feeds

@Mohini Publisher, feeds is not available for Lightning Web Components.
Reference: From documentation we are not able to view this as Lightning web component. FYI old question and comments reference.
